# How can i obtain the value of f1 as 1 in the following json array - '[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]' using inbuilt functions

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I am not able to obtain the value of a json array

```
select json_extract_path('[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]','f1')
```

when I tried using this inbuilt function it provides me null value.

It gives the output as null value, I would expect the return value to be 1.

Comment: The path to that value is `'{3, f1}'`, not `'{f1}'` - you missed the array index?

Comment: [Here are a few (all?) ways](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=db0711652f6871cfac97380865525db7) of achieving the desired result

Comment: When I try to find the array length it gives me value as 5, then how can I obtain the value of f1 as 1

Comment: @Sarah What does this have to do with the array length?

Comment: Yes This works ..select '[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]'::json #> '{3,f1}' and also this select json_extract_path('[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]','3','f1') ..Thnks Bergi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to access the array element by index:

```
select json_extract_path('[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]', '3', 'f1')
--                                                        ^^^^
```

Alternatively, you can use the `#>` operator with an array, or chain two `->` operators:

```
select '[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]'::json #> '{3,f1}'
select '[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]'::json -> 3 -> 'f1'
```

If you don't know that you are dealing with an array, or don't know the index at which your object is located, you could try using the new Postgres 12 [json paths](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) which automatically unwrap arrays:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first('[1,2,3,{"f1":1,"f2":[5,6]},4]', '$.f1')
```